# Marking Text from one annotation to another

Tags: uima, ruta

I'mI'm trying to annotate some Text inbetween two annotations. While this seems simple enough, I want to explicitly exclude passages of text that contain another annotation.

Let's say I previously anannotated the last Token of the Document and some POIs as several other annotations. now I want to SHIFT the last POI Annotation of the Document to that Token. But there mustn't be other POIs in that text.

What I currently do:

```
POI1 {->SHIFT(POI1,1,3)} ANY*?{-CONTAINS(POI2)} EndToken;
```

Ruta will still annotate every other Text containing POI2 annotations with this rule.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule won't work because `ANY*` doesn't have a stopper, so the star-greedy quantifier `*` overrides the `EndToken`. Additionally, you would normally use `CONTAINS` to check for an annotation **exclusively** inside another. Therefore the `PARTOF` condition is indicated for your case.

Within UIMA Ruta you could use at least two approaches to tackle your problem:

1.) Boundary Matching - annotates the text between predefined boundaries

```
(Annotation1 ANY+{-PARTOF(Annotation2)} Annotation3){-> Annotation4};
```

2.) Transformation - modifies the offset of the target annotation (your solution)

```
Annotation1{->SHIFT(Annotation1,1,2)} Annotation2;
```

If your goal is to just change the offsets of the POI1 annotation, then the following rule should work:

```
POI1{->SHIFT(POI1,1,3)} ANY*?{-PARTOF(POI2), -PARTOF(EndToken)} EndToken;
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! A little edit to your (so far) working solution:
`ANY*?{AND(-PARTOF(POI2),-PARTOF(EndToken))}`
(Added the AND for the two Conditions)

Comment: Furthermore, I think I misunderstood the way Ruta handles ANY*?. I thought of it looking for any amount of tokens and treating it as one single one and then applying my CONTAINS Condition. But it rather looks for each single Token, matches the Condition and heads over to the next one.
Maybe @Peter Kluegel or another dev could comment on this if they see this someday.

Comment: That's correct. Ruta treats `ANY` as a single seed of any kind at a time. However, you could tell it to go over multiple `ANY`s and check the condition fulfillment afterwards. For example: `(ANY[1,5]){-CONTAINS(POI2) -> POI1} EndToken;`. In this case it will take 5 `ANY`s at a time and test against the `CONTAINS` condition.

Comment: Does this still apply to star greedy or reluctant? i.e. (ANY*?){....} ?

Comment: Yes, it applies to both star greedy and star reluctant, but  `*?`  will stop matching on new `ANY`s once the condition is fulfilled. The star greedy would just go till then end of your text and evaluate the condition on its span for each `ANY`; therefore you would get as many matches as the number of tokens, where each match is shorter by a token.